# Marker offset shortcut does not work

Tags: interface, tracking, shortcut, movie-clip-editor

In version *2.72* when tracking markers are in use in movie clip editor, normally I could move marker with offset from original position to new one in purpose to skip some frames from place where originally marker is not able to track that place. And rather to use settings in properties panel, I can also use shortcut <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to move marker with offset using mouse.

In *Blender 2.77* somehow that shortcut is not working. When I want move marker pressing shortcut <kbd>G</kbd> I can move marker to new tracking place, but when I want move marker with just offset <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> it's not working.
 And I must use panel properties to change offset of that marker.

How I can fix that problem? Maybe is some settings wrong? 
 I try import shortcut settings from earlier version of blender, but that didn't help.

Comment: Can't confirm. Double `G` works as expected in 2.77a on linux at least. Depending on your OS/System, consider to report this as bug on https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: No issues here either... Using 2.77 GG works fine...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. 
I had accidentally locked the track in the movie clip editor dope sheet.
Once I un-padlocked it and gg worked again.